# Jordan decomposition of a restriction to a stable sub space

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

having a question regarding the following problem:

f is an endomorphism from V to V, and its Jordan-Chevalley-Decomposition is f=h+n where h is semisimple and n is nil-potent.

No we have an f-stable subspace W of V, I am pretty sure that W is stable under h and n too,  I can't seem to find a prove and I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Any help would be appreciated :)